# Tomcat/JSP Help: Current File/Directory Listing?

Tags: jsp

I'm usually a PHP programmer and there has been two areas that JSP has me at a fit.
The first area I'm having an issue with is dealing with the "." directory. Say I have a .jsp file stored in

```
C:\..\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\example\x.jsp
```

and the url for it is

```
http://www.example.com/example/x.jsp
```

In php, when I place a code like this

```
$files = scandir("./")
```

I'll get all the files in

```
C:\..\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\example
```

PHP starts the "." directory at the directory where your page is in.

JSP on the otherhand doesn't. Putting a code like this

```
java.io.File dir = new java.io.File("./")
```

It points me to the **C:..\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0** folder instead when I want to  traverse the example folder. I am creating links with the assumption that "." starts out at the current directory not the server head directory. Is there a way extract the current directory of a file like in php?

Comment: No, you shouldn't be extracting a directory in a JSP.  Java web development isn't exactly like PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat and Java web development is different.

You should be packaging your apps in a WAR file that acts as the context for your web app.

You should not be putting functionality or code in JSPs.  I'd recommend learning JSTL and be sure to put nothing but tags in your pages.

JSPs should be communicating with servlets that do the work and put the results in the page context.  Pages should do nothing but render results that are given to them.

Comment: What Im trying to do: all of my pages have an iframe(yes iframe) that links them to a x.jsp (was x.php). The x.jsp grab the http referer and look for that in all of the files in a specific folder (in example\specific). If it finds a mention of the http referer in a file it will display a certain info on the file. So I would need a webpage that would dynamically be able to read through files on the system. Does JSTL allow for this feature? Would I have to put all my code into servlets and call them from a JSP? I'm am as new as you can be to JSP. I only need to know it for the next couple weeks.

Comment: Now that's a pretty unhelpful answer. There are definitely use cases for small chunks of logic in a JSP page. Anyway, he just wanted to get the cwd. He could try request.getRequestURI ().

Comment: That's your opinion.  I stand by the answer.  Have you tried getRequestURI()?  Does that help?